# Is semiconductor wafer neutral after ion implantation?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

If ions are implanted in a silicon wafer as the term 'ion implantation' suggests, how can the wafer be electrically neutral after the semiconductor doping? Aren't the ions ions electrically charged? Or do we add/remove electrons from the wafer at the same time to keep the wafer neutral?

Comment: Electrons flow back into the wafer to the site where the ion implants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, an electrical current neutralizes the wafer.

One uses ions in order to accelerate them to kinetic energies that will penetrate the wafer to a certain depth. The ions in this technique are positive. The wafer should not repel the ion beam, so it is kept at ground potential.

Comment: Indeed, if you don’t bad things happen like luttle lightening bolt discharges vainly trying to keep the wafer closer to ground...